# Stacked Vega Lite chart with category text in middle of bars

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to place category labels in the centre of my bars in a vega lite spec.  I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `stack` transform combined with a `calculate` transform that computes the midpoint between the start and end to compute label placement.

Here's an example (or view in vega lite editor [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegEYTQFMBPAOgCsBnAewDsQBfAGhAHcBLMKAC3gEYADEJZRkEWpQBm1ZAFt4AbVAQA5iuSEV0QotDUADhkqJ5LSe0KowGYhasgWESjbvWGAXRbrqifbmKKIJTsUDosAG4EFlAB7syglDAAxgDWLpbWXsg+fgFwCiCRyNGxLDTIULog5hlGIWEgMmCEyBjNlEmEtGDstCqMcUygSRCoSYio2hgAFJBQJqS2GQD6iQRQAAQA1HMLS1bLXWAAlNgATA4gTkYmy-tgy7KcAyyTxC1VsgRpCCAx+jo4CB8K1mCAuklqD0+vBQAAPWF-YgAjC0ahPWijS41exAoolRgsPKgf6AkAAR0Q4igIWg7HCDRx1iB91WMAqhJAxAuv1JGEp1NpNIZ2Nc6QOR05kNQMkRfKBaIxWLMYqBwVCjAY8RAX2QPxJyLJoThlRY0tlQNwk1SnIhUN6-V+xOqqqCt1ZT0ySJRQIFtBpMGFOjBxsqvyZdQ1YIRvMNqPRvWVLtqeKihBimo8DCAA))

Note that the `aggregate` transform is only needed because, with this dataset, there is one row per year.

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "width": 1000,
  "transform": [
     {
      "aggregate": [{
       "op": "sum",
       "field": "yield",
       "as": "yield"
      }],
      "groupby": ["site", "variety"]
    },
     {
        "stack": "yield",
        "groupby": ["variety"],
        "sort": [{"field": "site", "order": "descending"}]
      },
      {
        "calculate": "(datum.yield_start +datum.yield_end)/2",
        "as": "sum_yield_mid"
      }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "variety"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "yield_start"},
        "y2": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "yield_end"},
        "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "site"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "black"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "sum_yield_mid", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"field": "site"},
        "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "variety"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```